# Image upload with produtId in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular11, ng2-image-upload

I tried a lot of ways to upload images to the server but none of them worked. The below method works but I cannot transfer productId along with the image.

**component.ts code**

```js
    selectedFile: ImageSnippet;

    class ImageSnippet {
    constructor(public src: string, public file: File) {
     }
    }

    processFile(imageInput: any) {
    const file: File = imageInput.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', (event: any) => {

      this.selectedFile = new ImageSnippet(event.target.result, file);

      this.imageService.uploadImage(this.selectedFile.file).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

**service.ts**

```js
    public uploadImage(image: File): Observable<Response> {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', image);

    // @ts-ignore
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Upload', formData);
    }
```

**HTML File**

```html
    <input type="file" #imageInput
                       accept="image/*">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="processFile(imageInput)"><i
                  class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                  Upload
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple key value pairs inside formData. In your image upload service just append product id as well after you append the image.

```
formData.append('image', image);
formData.append('productId', //add productId here );
```

Comment: @Gannesh Krishna ProductId is dynamically need to add

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? When you say dynamically, how is it received/generated and where do we have to add it? @ashfan

Comment: @Gannesh Krishna  I'm getting productId via my API and I can able to print it in the console. Assign productId to variable and i need to pass it to my API

Comment: @Gannesh Krishna I fixed that from my API now it's working. Thanks for support.